# $\mathsf{ZF}$ is not finitely axiomatizable

Tags: logic, set-theory

As we know a first order theory $T$ is finitely axiomatizable if there is a finite set $F\subseteq T$ of axioms such that $F\vdash \sigma$ for every $\sigma \in T$.

How we can prove if $\mathsf{ZF}$ is consistent, then $\mathsf{ZF}$ is not finitely axiomatizable? By using the Reflection Theorem or any other if we could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the proof in Kunen's famous book "Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs" (North Holland, 1980).  It is Corollary IV 7.7 on page 138, and it does make use of reflection.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $\text{ZF}$ is consistent and $\text{ZF}$ is fnitely axiomatizable. Let $\Gamma \subset \text{ZF}$ be a finite subset such that $\Gamma \vdash \text{ZFC}$. Referring to Jech or Kunen, $\text{ZF} \vdash \text{Reflection Theorem}$. So $\text{ZF} \vdash \text{Con}(\Gamma)$. Since $\Gamma \vdash \text{ZF}$, $\text{ZF} \vdash \text{Con}(\text{ZF})$. If $\text{ZF}$ is consistent, this contradicts the Second Incompleteness Theorem.

Comment: You do not even need the second incompleteness: $\Gamma$ proves that there is an $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha\models \Gamma$, so if $V_\beta\models\Gamma$, $\beta$ is not the least such ordinal.

Comment: I see that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle discusses both these techniques.