# An infinite set of axioms in ZF? What does that mean?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axioms, peano-axioms

Before write this question, I looked around enough in this forum for a possible answer and although there are many similar questions, I couldn't find one answer which understand or satisfies me. I did read somewhere a long time ago that Zermelo-Frankael has an infinite set of axioms. Moreover, the same is true for Peano's system and as I perceive there are many differences among the systems with a finite set and infinite set of axioms (I don't know exactly even what the latter means in practice)

So, can you explain me please what does the sentence "Zermelo-Frankael has an infinite set of axioms" mean?

Any kind of comments and answers are welcomed, although I would prefer a sort of answer or comment which doesn't assume a deep understanding of the above-mentioned notions.

Comment: I don't quite understand your confusion. ZF is a set of sentences; it happens to be an infinite set, as opposed to a finite set. Or are you asking something else?

Comment: why the set of axioms is infinite? That's what i don't get.

Comment: It is infinite because Replacement and Separation (if we are using Separation) are each quite explicitly an infinite collection of sentences, just like the induction scheme in first-order Peano arithmetic is an infinite collection of sentences. One can produce finitely axiomatized set theories. The most accessible one is NBG.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thank you for your response, however I still have the same   question for some reason. Can you tell me please how can a single axiom scheme produce an infinite set of axioms?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris An axiom scheme is just a collection of infinitely many different axioms, which intuitively "look similar." Does this help?

Comment: Here is another example, from real-closed fields. We want to say that every polynomial of odd degree has a root. In order to say it for all polynomials, we need to have separate axioms for degree $3$, $5$, and so on. For degree $3$ we say that for all $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3$ with $a_0\ne 0$ there is an $x$ such that $a_0x^3+a_1x^2+a_2x+a_3=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "what does it mean" you mean "what does it mean" I have to ask what do you mean, what does it mean? Saying that ZF has infinitely many axioms means exactly what it says. There are infinitely many primes. There are only finitely many natural numbers less than $3$. There are infinitely many axioms of ZF.

Probably you actually understand that, and you're just puzzled because you see presentations of the axioms in finitely much space, making it *look* as though there are only finitely many axioms. No, some of those "axioms" are, formally, not axioms but rather infinite sets of axioms. This is using the word "axiom" in a formal sense, requiring it to be a formula of first-order logic.

Consider the axiom, or rather axiom schema, of Separation. Informally this says that for any set $A$ and any property $P$ that the elements of $A$ may or may not satisfy, $$\{x\in A:P(x)\}$$ is a set. The reason this counts as infinitely many axioms is that in the formal system in question there is no way to "say" "for every property $P$", so formally we have infinitely many axioms, one for each $P$.

For example, the existence of $$\{x\in\Bbb R:x>0\}$$follows from one *instance of* Separation, while the existence of $$\{x\in\Bbb R:x^2>3\}$$requires another instance of the axiom scheme. Formally two different axioms, one for the predicate $x>0$ and one for the predicate $x^2>3$.

Why not just add "for every property $P$" to the formal system? Then it becomes a "second-order" system, and second-order logic is harder.

Comment: I think you helped me David. And what do I mean by that? I mean, thank you for your answer! :P

Comment: @mayer_vietoris It may be worth pointing out that not only is the standard axiomatization of ZF infinite but, in fact, *any* axiomatization of ZF is infinite (so it is not that we chose the "wrong" list of axioms and some more clever finite list would have worked as well).

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo thank you for your comment. How do you justify this? Is there any theorem or something subtle that I am missing?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris The fact that ZF is not finitely axiomatizable is not trivial. Hints at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739070/mathsfzf-is-not-finitely-axiomatizable

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the schema is a "template", and we can easily recognize when a statement written in the language of set theory fits the template, and is therefore an axiom of ZF. This means that while indeed ZF has no finite axiomatization, there are only finitely many ways that an axiom of ZF can look like.

Comment: Rather that quantify over logical predicates (like $P$ here) and have one only one axiom of Separation, it was thought preferable to  have infinitely many such axioms that did not quantity over predicates, I guess.

Comment: @DanChristensen Yes, since quantification over predicates is not first-order, and that makes the model theory and proof theory terrible. (For example, we wouldn't have any nice proof system.) By contrast, the model theory and proof theory of infinitely-axiomatized first-order theories are quite nice.