# Set of axioms extending ZF

Tags: logic, set-theory

Let $S$ be any set of axioms extending ZF. Suppose $\phi_1, ... \phi_n \in S$. Show that, if from $\phi_1, ... \phi_n$ one can prove all axioms of $S$, then $S$ is inconsistent. Conclude that ZF is not finitely axiomatizable.

So in order to show that $S$ is inconsistent, I need to show $S \vdash (\phi_1 \land ... \land\phi_n )$ and $S \vdash \lnot (\phi_1 \land ... \land\phi_n )$. But how do I do this and how do I conclude that ZF is not finitely axiomatizable?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739070/mathsfzf-is-not-finitely-axiomatizable)

Comment: More precisely, you should conclude that if ZF is consistent then it is not finitely axiomatizable. Hopefully that makes it clear how we can conclude that from the result.